# Avalonia is unable to resolve a namespace

Tags: c#, xaml, avaloniaui, avalonia

So I was using Avalonia, and needed to write a DataTemplate for a specific type. But when I set the DataType to the required type and run it, it throws this error.

```
D:\Some\Random\Path\Tachyon\src/App.axaml(9,23,9,23): Avalonia error XAMLIL:
Unable to resolve type FileTabItem from namespace https://github.com/avaloniaui Line 9, position 23. [D:\Some\Random\Path\Tachyon\Tachyon.csproj]
The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

This is where I need to access the namespace:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="srv:FileTabItem">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

and how I've declared the `srv` variable(or whatever u call it idk I'm no expert in terminology)

```
<Window xmlns:srv="clr-namespace:Tachyon.Services">
```

Complete xaml file: https://paste.myst.rs/1eoeh40t

And yes, their is a namespace with FileTabItem as a class in it.

Comment: Please edit the code into your question, and also try to minimize it down to only what is relevant. The reason why we ask for code to be present in the questions is that links typically become outdated and lead to nothing, which means in the future this question is worthless. This is all the more important given the page you linked to actually states the expiration date, which is just a week away.

Comment: sure, ill separate out the relevant code and still leave the link there in case anyone wants to check the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

Avalonia also supports a Xamarin Forms style "using:" syntax for namespaces that tries harder to find namespaces for you...

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:srv="using:Tachyon.Services">
```

The only documentation I've found so far is in the features pull request:
[Feature: alternative "using:" syntax to include namespace to XAML file](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/4417)